# sound keeps switching from line out to headphones randomly

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the sound keeps cutting off then comes back in an instant but it is still very noticeable and annoying, I've seen that it switches from **line out** to **headphones** which creates that laggy audio effect.
I don't know the sound driver(it's probably alsa) but I've got *pulseaudio volume control* so I don't know which one I'm using right now.

if you need any more clarification I'm more than happy to answer ^^.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a fix for two months i encountered a solution. You have to use hdajackretask to set your "Green Headphone out" to override and not present. Then you click on install boot override, reboot and the problem it's gone. Hope you find that solution usefull.